# Using Pipe in Make File

Tags: bash, makefile

I'm trying to create a make command that uses a pipe. But the command is not executing as expected.

Example

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash

all:
    $(shell ps aux | grep -i someProcName)
```

Output:

```
bash: kls602: command not found
grep: kls602: No such file or directory
grep: 46905: No such file or directory
grep: 0.0: No such file or directory
grep: 0.0: No such file or directory
grep: 4306668: No such file or directory
grep: 6480: No such file or directory
grep: s008: No such file or directory
grep: S: No such file or directory
grep: 12:22PM: No such file or directory
grep: 0:00.57: No such file or directory
...
```

It's as if the output of ps is being taken in as the file to search in the grep command. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

So how do you write semi complex bash command in make? I would prefer a better answer than "Just run a bash script instead of putting the command in a makefile".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `$(shell...)` in a recipe is an anti-pattern.  You should never do it except in the most unusual, bizarre situations.  A recipe *IS* a shell script, so running `$(shell ...)` there is, at best, redundant.

Second, read what [the `shell` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html) does:

> The `shell` function performs the same function that backquotes (‘`’) perform in most shells: it does command expansion. This means that it takes as an argument a shell command and evaluates to the output of the command.

So your understanding of what's happening is exactly correct, and that's exactly what it's supposed to do.

You should write this simply as:

```
all:
        ps aux | grep -i someProcName
```

Comment: :-( I'm not sure where I got in my head that I had to wrap commands in $(shell...). Thanks!

Comment: Using `$(shell ...)` is an anti-pattern?  That's just crazy.  It's obviously good to get this newbie on track with (no real need to use `$(shell ...)` in this case), but you're going to say that any tool that's powerful is bad?  In that case, all power saws are also bad and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Please re-read: it's wrong to use `$(shell ...)` **in a recipe**.  A recipe is, by definition, already running in a shell, so using make's `$(shell ...)` function adds confusion and provides zero benefits.  Anything you could do in the `shell` function could more easily, and more understandably, just be written without invoking `shell`.

Comment: how to store output of such command in makefile variable?

Comment: In that case, you WOULD use the `shell` function.  That's what it's for (not for use in recipes).